# Get specific values from array/object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Totally stumped here.

I have the following object:

```
var stStatus = new StockStatus({
  "3":{
    "is_in_stock":false,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"Out of Stock",
    "product_id":"9",
    "stockalert":""
  },
  "5":{
    "is_in_stock":true,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"",
    "product_id":"10"
   },
  "88":{
    "is_in_stock":true,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"",
    "product_id":"296"
    }
});
```

that is being dynamically created, so I don't know the 3, 5, or 88 numbers before hand. I'm trying to figure out how to get the the 3,5,88 and their tied is_in_stock and product_id.

Trying to get it to basically only console.log the product_id and 3,5,88 numbers if is_in_stock is false

Totally stumped.

Comment: what makes `StockStatus`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using `strStatus`? What does `StockStatus` do?

Comment: Are you looking for `Object.keys`?

Comment: Some weird Magento stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys in an array.

Then use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the array and match the key with the object.

```
var m ={
  "3":{
    "is_in_stock":false,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"Out of Stock",
    "product_id":"9",
    "stockalert":""
  },
  "5":{
    "is_in_stock":true,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"",
    "product_id":"10"
   },
  "88":{
    "is_in_stock":true,
    "custom_status_icon":"",
    "custom_status":"",
    "product_id":"296"
    }
}

var _keyArray = Object.keys(m)
_keyArray.forEach(function(item){
 document.write('<pre>'+(m[item]['is_in_stock'])+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L210xknn/)

Comment: I've never understood the appeal of prefixing variable names with underscore. Why do you use it? (you're not wrong, I just don't get it)

Comment: Underscore in variable name, `document.write`, jsFiddle... SO has stack snippets, which support `console.log`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is also to represent a private variable, Check this [LINK](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/dollar-and-underscore.htm)

Comment: This is working excellently. I have this fork here https://jsfiddle.net/fq8qc17r/1/ where I'm getting almost what I need. But can't seem to log/write the first number they're contained in..

Comment: @Octoxan not sure what you mean by *first number*. I am assuming you are referring to the key that is 3,5 88 and so on. If it is so then check this https://jsfiddle.net/fq8qc17r/2/

Comment: What is new new StockStatus

Comment: Why fake private variables with a naming convention when JS has them? Either use a closure, or let/const.

Comment: Thanks. I got it figured out with a combination of this and some Magento PHP stuff now. =]

Comment: @user2181397 Trying to learn how to nest this now. https://jsfiddle.net/fq8qc17r/4/ Trying to write/log every "products" key that is set to false. If you wouldn't mind taking a look

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `Object.keys`.

```
var keys = Object.keys(stStatus)
```

should give you an array containing all the keys in this instance. You can then use the result like this:

```
stStatus[keys[0]]
```

to access the first field; analogous for the rest.